# angular 2 rc router angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I converted my angular2 test app from beta-14 to rc1. I got the following error

```
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(…)
```

The code that issue this error is here

```
    346 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke = function (targetZone, callback, applyThis, applyArgs, source) {
    347     return this._invokeZS
    348         ? this._invokeZS.onInvoke(this._invokeDlgt, this.zone, targetZone, callback, applyThis, applyArgs, source)
    349         : callback.apply(applyThis, applyArgs);
    350 };
```

My code that caused the error is main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {provide, ComponentRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
// ,LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS }    from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common'

import {AppComponent} from './appShell/app.component';
import {appInjector} from './login/auth.injector';
import {Authentication} from './login/auth.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  //provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: location.pathname}),
  Authentication,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
])//.catch(err => console.error(err));
.then((appRef: ComponentRef<any>) => {
  // store a reference to the application injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);
});
```

I used router-deprecated for backward compatibility. This code used to work with beta-14.

I used config.js from https://plnkr.co/edit/yRKhoOelf2uJ3yAsdIMm?p=preview.

LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy is commented out because it's no longer included in router-deprecated. Is it replaced by

```
provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: location.pathname})  ?
```

And more important, What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You can find `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` in `@angular/common`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `config.js` is wrong.

I forked the official plunk found in [the doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and it doesn't show any error.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wbRp2k67JiXbN2RFlaUc?p=preview

As commented above, you can find `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` in `@angular/common`.

Comment: I changed the config.js and it passed the main.ts. But on leaving the  app.component.ts it gave this browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!. Any idea?  But your answer to my original questions are correct.
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor]

Comment: Do you use `Router` in your code? If so, how is it imported? I cannot tell what's going on without looking at your app.component.ts

Comment: Yes. I would make a separate follow up post. See you there:)

Comment: It's here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088964/rc1-router-no-provider-for-router